# laravel css and jquery 403 error

Tags: php, css, laravel

I'm using laravel 3.x and wamp I have been working for hours to fix the public folder to remove it and I have succeeded.
My problem is that when I go to http://laravel.dev css files and js file are not loaded, in my console I get a 403 error NetworkError:

```
403 Forbidden - http://localhost/laravel/public/laravel/css/style.css
```

Here's my `.htaccess` from public folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Can you show us VirtualHost definition in conf file ?

Comment: Can you please show how you get the http://localhost/laravel/public/laravel/css/style.css link? Because you should have a link to http://laravel.dev/css/style.css, not the one before.

Comment: thank you i've just managed to fix it i forgot to modify the application.php file url site to larave.dev

Comment: somehow now all other websites in my localhost are now getting 404 not found error but if i remove the config from vhosts and http-conf it's all ok again except the laravel site.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to
`your-project-folder/app/config/app.php`

and replace this line

```
'url' => 'http://localhost',
```

with Your New Domain Name.

This problem occurs when you move your Laravel app to a new domain. Example, from your localhost to a live production environment. CHEERS!

Comment: work for me if added base URL directly like above want to use from .env file